# Textarea value outside of textarea in modal : weird

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, textarea

I have a modal which pops out a form, allowing an admin to edit/update a news story. It works just fine, updating the database and everything, only the 'Story' piece appears outside of the textarea box when in the modal window.

A few pictures will illustrate my point and confusion.

[image: Look YAY is the story text from the database]

'Look YAY' is the current story, being pulled into the area underneath the textarea

[image: Prior to hitting the enter button]

adding in a new story

[image: New story gets slapped into the bottom but...]

the new story is now in the database, but underneath the textarea box in the modal

[image: on the actual form page (where the modal loads from), it is diplayed properly]

yet on the actual form page it is where it is suppose to be

I've checked and rechecked my code, but my only thought is that jquery-UI is somehow interfering with the textarea since, by definition, the code within the modal is equivalent to that of the Edit News form.

Here is the form code for the story element

```
    Story<br/>
    <textarea name="edit_story"/><?php print $row['story'];?></textarea>
```

and the jquery which pops it open

```
$('.edit').click(function(event){
        //don't follow the link
        event.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this).parent();
        //load in the html from the form at edit_news
        var formDOM = $("<div />").load($link.attr('href')+' #edit_form', function() { 
                //clear the dialog box
        $('#dialog-edit').empty();
                // Append to the page 
                $('#dialog-edit').append(formDOM);
                //make the dialog
                $('#dialog-edit').dialog({
                    autoOpen:false,
                    title:$link.attr('title'),
                    width:530,
                    height:465
                })
                //open it up
                $('#dialog-edit').dialog('open');
                $('#edit_form').submit(function(event){
                    //knock out its form processing
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                type    : "post",  
                        url     : $link.attr('href'),  
                        data    : $(this).serialize(),  
                        success : function() { 
                            //close dialog
                    $('#dialog-edit').dialog('close');
                            }
                    })
                })
        })
    });
```

What is going on here?

if anyone has any ideas please toss them my way. It may very well be a n00bish programming error, which I will gracefully accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are closing `<textarea>` tag before printing text into it. Fix:

```
<textarea name="edit_story"><?php print $row['story'];?></textarea>
```

Comment: I can't accept it for another 10 minutes :C but thank you. I feel a fool.

Comment: As a programmer, it's a must. I had this problem once. ;]

Comment: No problem, if you accept it in the future, I'll be happy. One more tip - use Firebug to see what's actually happening with your code. You'd see that text is outside textarea.